# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia Video quality and facing mode constraints

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm not able to specify **video quality** and **camera facing** constraints together.
Is there a way to combine the below constraints?

```
{
  audio: true,
  video: { width: 1280, height: 720 }
}

{ audio: true, video: { facingMode: "user" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: getConstraints(1280, 720) });

function getConstraints(videowidth, videoheight) {
    constraints = {
        facingMode: { exact: "environment" },
        width: { min: videowidth, ideal: videowidth, max: videowidth },
        height: { min: videoheight, ideal: videoheight, max: videoheight },
        frameRate: { min: 5, max: 8 }
    };
    return constraints;
}
```